# Largest file not being displayed

Tags: c#

I'm doing a Programming assignment which is based around file sorting. I'm having a problem with working out the largest file. What I want the below code to do is to show the largest file in my system. Instead, it's going through a full listing of all the files I have.

Here is my code for this particular section:

```
                for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
                {

                    fileSize = files[index].Length;

                    long largestSoFar = 0;

                    folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows");
                    files = folderInfo.GetFiles();

                    if (fileSize > largestSoFar)
                    {                            
                        string fileName = files[index].Name;
                        largestSoFar = files[index].Length;
                        long largestFile = largestSoFar;
                        Console.WriteLine("Largest file: {0}, {1} bytes", fileName, largestSoFar);
                        // It should be that only the largest file gets shown.
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It's my first time using this site. If my explanation is a bit vague or you don't know what I'm asking, do let me know and I'll do my best to simplify my explanation.

Comment: you need to track that outside of your loop and print after the loop completes.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your loop, step multiple times through it using F10 and inspect your variables, or add watches and see what happens.

Comment: So basically I need to put 'largestSoFar' AFTER the if statement? Or am I completely misunderstanding the point.

Comment: The value for largestSoFar is coming out as 0, which I know is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code

```
long largestSoFar = 0;
string largestFileName = string.Empty;
DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows");
FileInfo[] files = folderInfo.GetFiles();

for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
{

    long fileSize = files[index].Length;

    if (fileSize > largestSoFar)
    {
        largestFileName = files[index].Name;
        largestSoFar = files[index].Length;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Largest file: {0}, {1} bytes", largestFileName, largestSoFar);
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined `largestSoFar` inside loop so it is initialized every time and that's why you're effectively iterating over all files. Do it oustide the loop and it will eventually contain the largest file. After loop finishes you can output all the details

```
        var fileName = "";
        long largestSoFar = 0;
        var folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows");
        var files = folderInfo.GetFiles();

        for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
            {

                long fileSize = (long) files[index].Length;
                if (fileSize > largestSoFar)
                {                            
                    fileName = files[index].Name;
                    largestSoFar = (long) files[index].Length;
                }
            }

            //write largest file information
            Console.WriteLine("Largest file: {0}, {1} bytes", fileName, largestSoFar);
            // It should be that only the largest file gets shown.
```

Comment: I've defined largestSoFar with the variable 'long'. If I tried to define it again in the code, it would come up with an error message. Is there any coding that's in the wrong place or is it just that I'm missing something?

Comment: don't define it inside the loop and just move it outside as in my example

Comment: @ChrisWaddington I assumed you had the folderInfo and files declared somewhere above in your code. See my update to code